# Some questions about quaternions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, quaternions

It is possible make something like complexification of a real vector space using quaternions?
If yes, it's similar to complex case or there are considerable differences?
Has been studied a quaternion analysis?
thank you!

Comment: $V\otimes_{\Bbb R}\Bbb H$.

Comment: Googling "quaternion analysis" and "quaternionic analysis" (more common) turns up tens of thousands of hits. Also, the obvious "quaternization algebra" and "quaternification" generate relevant hits.

Answer (score 3):

It is no longer a vector space, but a module over a division algebra. Complexification is generalized by "extension of scalars," where an [$R$-module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29) (resp. [$R$-algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_%28ring_theory%29)) $A$ is turned into an $S$-module (resp. $S$-algebra) via [tensoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), $A_S\cong S\otimes_R A$. (Here $S$ is a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) containing $R$ as a subring.)

Comment: Quick note on terminology: Some sources do not require the underlying ring to be commutative to speak of a vector space; hence these still consider $V \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb H$ a vector space.